# OpenGL, WinAPI | garbage values to unicode(I think, L"") string

Tags: c++, c, string, winapi

I want to try and learn OpenGL, I know C++ and I found a [site](https://www.cprogramming.com/graphics-programming.html) with C++/OpenGL tutorials, this site also teaches a few things about WinAPI,bcs "our" programms are going to be Windows applications. In [this](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/opengl_first_windows_app.html) tutorial it has the code of "our" first Windows application. The code **(it doesn't compile)**:

```
/*  Trim fat from windows*/
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 
#pragma comment(linker, "/subsystem:windows")
/*  Pre-processor directives*/
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
/*  Windows Procedure Event Handler*/
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
    /*  Device Context*/
    HDC hDC; 
    /*  Text for display*/
    char string[] = "Hello, World!"; 
    /*  Switch message, condition that is met will execute*/
    switch(message)
    {
        /*  Window is being created*/
        case WM_CREATE: 
            return 0;
            break;
        /*  Window is closing*/
        case WM_CLOSE: 
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
            break;
        /*  Window needs update*/
        case WM_PAINT: 
            hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd,&paintStruct);
            /*  Set txt color to blue*/
            SetTextColor(hDC, COLORREF(0x00FF0000));
            /*  Display text in middle of window*/
            TextOut(hDC,150,150,string,sizeof(string)-1);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &paintStruct);
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return (DefWindowProc(hwnd,message,wParam,lParam));
}
/*  Main function*/
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX  windowClass;        //window class
    HWND        hwnd;               //window handle
    MSG         msg;                //message
    bool        done;               //flag saying when app is complete
    /*  Fill out the window class structure*/
    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    windowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    windowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    windowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = "MyClass";
    windowClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    /*  Register window class*/
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&windowClass))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    /*  Class registerd, so now create window*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,     //extended style
        "MyClass",          //class name
        "A Real Win App",       //app name
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW |       //window style
        WS_VISIBLE |
        WS_SYSMENU,
        100,100,            //x/y coords
        400,400,            //width,height
        NULL,               //handle to parent
        NULL,               //handle to menu
        hInstance,          //application instance
        NULL);              //no extra parameter's
    /*  Check if window creation failed*/
    if (!hwnd)
        return 0;
    done = false; //initialize loop condition variable
    /*  main message loop*/
    while(!done)
    {
        PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,NULL,NULL,PM_REMOVE);
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) //check for a quit message
        {
            done = true; //if found, quit app
        }
        else
        {
            /*  Translate and dispatch to event queue*/
            TranslateMessage(&msg); 
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

**It didn't compile**, it had a few errors so **I changed it a bit**:

```
/*  Trim fat from windows*/
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 
#pragma comment(linker, "/subsystem:windows")
/*  Pre-processor directives*/
#include <tchar.h> //couldn't find stdafx.h
#include <windows.h>
/*  Windows Procedure Event Handler*/
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
    /*  Device Context*/
    HDC hDC;
    /*  Text for display*/
    wchar_t string[] = L"F*CK!!!! It doesn't work, why am I getting Kanji? WTF\0"; // fixed error: char not compatible, char -> wchar_t
    /*  Switch message, condition that is met will execute*/
    switch (message)
    {
        /*  Window is being created*/
    case WM_CREATE:
        return 0;
        break;
        /*  Window is closing*/
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
        break;
        /*  Window needs update*/
    case WM_PAINT:
        hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &paintStruct);
        /*  Set txt color to blue*/
        SetTextColor(hDC, COLORREF(0x00FF0000));
        /*  Display text in middle of window*/
        TextOut(hDC, 150, 150, string, sizeof(string) - 1);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &paintStruct);
        return 0;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return (DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam));
}
/*  Main function*/
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX  windowClass;        //window class
    HWND        hwnd;               //window handle
    MSG         msg;                //message
    bool        done;               //flag saying when app is complete
    /*  Fill out the window class structure*/
    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    windowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    windowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    windowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = L"MyClass"; // fixed error: char* not compatible with LPCWSTR
    windowClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    /*  Register window class*/
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&windowClass))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    /*  Class registerd, so now create window*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,     //extended style
        L"MyClass",          //class name | fixed error: char* not compatible with LPCWSTR
        L"A Real Win App",       //app name | fixed error: char* not compatible with LPCWSTR
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW |       //window style
        WS_VISIBLE |
        WS_SYSMENU,
        100, 100,            //x/y coords
        400, 400,            //width,height
        NULL,               //handle to parent
        NULL,               //handle to menu
        hInstance,          //application instance
        NULL);              //no extra parameter's
    /*  Check if window creation failed*/
    if (!hwnd)
        return 0;
    done = false; //initialize loop condition variable
    /*  main message loop*/
    while (!done)
    {
        PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE);
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) //check for a quit message
        {
            done = true; //if found, quit app
        }
        else
        {
            /*  Translate and dispatch to event queue*/
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

**Now it compiles**, but, **I get this**:[image: The "F*CK!!!! it doesn't work, why am I getting Kanji, WTF" is correct]
The **"F*CK!!!! it doesn't work, why am I getting Kanji, WTF"** is correct(Forgive me if it is not Kanji)

---

Thank you for listening(reading actually) to my problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace this:

```
TextOut(hDC, 150, 150, string, sizeof(string) - 1);
```

with this:

```
TextOut(hDC, 150, 150, string, wcslen(string));
```

`sizeof (string)` is in bytes, not characters.

Also, please don't spam language tags.  Just pick the one(s) that are relevant.

Comment: `string` is a compile-time constant, so there's not really a need to calculate its length at run time. Using Microsoft's [_countof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/countof-macro) or C++' [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) is perfectly fine.

Comment: @IInspectable I am aware, but using `wcslen` is more flexible.  One day, the string will have decayed to a pointer...

Comment: And when that happens, the compiler will helpfully fail to compile either of the alternatives I suggested. At least in C++ which the OP is using.

Comment: @PaulSanders excuse me, but what do you mean by "the string will have decayed to a pointer"? As far as I know a string variable is a pointer to an array of characters, but what "decayed to a pointer" actually means, what do you mean by "decayed"?

Comment: @platinoob_ If you pass a (C-style) string as a parameter to a function, then it decays to a pointer inside that function.  If you were then to use `sizeof` (or `_countof`), you would get the size of a `wchar_t *` (i.e. 8 in a 64 bit build), rather than the length of the string, and `std::size` will fail to compile.  I don't care what IInspectable says, I would use `wcslen` because it works everywhere.  Furthermore, `_countof` is an MSVC extension, so that's another reason to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter of `TextOut()` takes a **character** count, but you are passing it a **byte** count instead.

In the original code, the `string` array used `char` characters, and `sizeof(char)` is 1 byte, so the two counts were the same numeric value.  But you changed the code to use `wchar_t` characters instead, and on Windows `sizeof(wchar_t)` is 2 bytes.

So, by using `TextOut(..., string, sizeof(string) - 1)` with a `wchar_t` string, you are telling `TextOut()` that there are 2 times as many `wchar_t`s in the `string` array as there really are, and thus `TextOut()` goes out of bounds of the `string` array printing out random garbage from surrounding memory (consider yourself lucky the code didn't just crash outright from accessing memory it didn't own).

If you are going to use `sizeof()` in this manner, then to get the correct array element count, you need to divide the array's byte size by its element's byte size, eg:

```cpp
TextOut(..., string, (sizeof(string) / sizeof(string[0])) - 1)
```

You can replace that with the [`_countof()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/countof-macro?view=msvc-160) macro in Visual Studio (or equivalent in other compilers), eg:

```cpp
TextOut(..., string, _countof(string) - 1)
```

In C++11 and later, you should use [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) instead, eg:

```cpp
TextOut(..., string, std::size(string) - 1)
```

Note that if the `string` array is ever replaced with a `wchar_t*` pointer in the future, these solutions will not work anymore.  The `sizeof()` solution will still *compile* but will not produce the correct *result*.  But the `_countof()` and `std::size()` solutions will fail to compile, which is a good thing.  Then you will know that you need to replace it with a more appropriate solution, like `lstrlenW()`, `std::wstring::size()`, etc.

Comment: @IInspectable fixed

Answer (score 0):

You're using `sizeof(string)`. That's the number of bytes, not the number of characters. Since you're using C++, use `std::wstring::size()`.